# python script to add armature to outfit(.obj)

Tags: python, armature

We imported the avatar(.glb) and outfit(.obj) and invoked the armature

The following is the code

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.import_scene.gltf(filepath="D:\\avatars\\Aditya\\avatar\\nakedstand.glb", files=[{"name":"nakedstand.glb"}], import_pack_images=True,import_shading='NORMALS', loglevel=50)

bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath="D:\\avatars\\Aditya\\avatar\\outfit.obj")


bpy.ops.object.add(type='ARMATURE', enter_editmode=false)
ob = bpy.context.object
amt = ob.data
```

referred to the link [Armature Bone Global Local coordinates python scripting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98760/armature-bone-global-local-coordinates-python-scripting)

did not work out
am stuck how to add armature to the obj object ?